# I need help making a selection from an Array

Tags: java

Basically I need to pass on the price when they make a selection and have no idea how.

```
int selection;
String[] snacks = { "   (1): Chewing Gum", "   (2): Kit Kat", "   (3): Snickers", "   (4): Pop Tarts" };
int[] price = { 40, 75, 80, 90 };
System.out.println("Java Vending Machine");

for (int index = 0; index < snacks.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(snacks[index] + " -- " + price[index] + "¢");
}

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
selection = keyboard.nextInt(); 
return selection;
```

Comment: Give us some sample cases. It's unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is

```
// return selection;
return (selection > 0 && selection <= price.length) ? price[selection-1] : 0;
```

As another example,

```
// That ternary could also be written as
if (selection > 0 && selection <= price.length) {
  return price[selection-1];
}
return 0;
```